# How to difference a series in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series column in pandas dataframe.  How do I create a new field wth a difference=1?

e.g. somethin like this

```
  df['exr_ln_diff'] = df['exr_ln'].difference(1)
```

Comment: see [`.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) and [`.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['exr_ln_diff'] = df['exr_ln'].diff()
```